# How to keep the currently selected rows highlighted even after disabling the row selection in jTable in java

Tags: java, swing, selection, highlight

I have a `JTable` in java which contains 5 rows(lets say) UI.

I select 2 rows and those 2 rows are highlighted and then I click on a button. Now in the code, on that button I am disabling the row selection so that I will not be able to select any more rows once I have clicked that button.

But the problem is the selection of those 2 rows is getting cleared means that in the code I can access those 2 selected rows but in the UI those rows are not highlighted after disabling.

Is there any way that I can keep that selection of rows in the UI even after disabling the row selection??

Comment: Grab a reference to the selected rows before you disable row selection.  Either that or replace the `SelectionModel` before hand, but you might as well go with the first option

Comment: Ok so I have a reference of selected rows before disabling. How would I be able to use it further..?

Comment: Store them somewhere, maybe provide a getter, it all comes down to the structure of your code

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom `ListSelectionModel` that allows you to toggle the selection state of the model.

```
public class ToggleListSelectionModel extends ListSelectionModel
{
    private boolean selectionEnabled = true;

    public ToggleListSelectionModel()
    {
        super();
    }

    public boolean isSelectionEnabled()
    {
        return selectionEnabled;
    }

    public void setSelectionEnabled(boolean selectionEnabled)
    {
        this.selectionEnabled = selectionEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void addSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) 
    {
        if (selectionEnabled)
            super.addSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
    }

    //  Override other add/remove methods
}
```

Then in the ActionListener of your button you can disable the selection state.

Answer (score -1):

without a code example it is difficult to help.
But I would recommend to set css classes for the selected rows.
With jQuery you can just do it like:

```
$(selector).addClass('yourCSSClass')
```

You can also delete the css class with .removeClass.

Or you can use .toggleClass which adds or removes the css class.

Comment: Its not jQuery or jsp. Its swing.